# compact(): Undefined variable: users

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relation

here i am trying to get all the project->id, which match with team->project_id and relation is working but my using variable $users showing undefined. What could be the problem??

here is the controller code

```
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role->id == 1) {
        $projects = Project::all();
        $teams = Team::all();
        foreach ($teams as $team) {
            $users = User::whereIn('id', $team->members)->get();
        }
        return view('project.index', compact('projects', 'users'));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: You need to defined it first, before the loop do `$users = null;`. Also note that your loop will overwrite `$users` for each iteration

Comment: You should also define a relation instead, so you can do `$users = $team->users;`

Comment: check you users table , probably the id is in your $team->members , is not exist in users table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing the users out of the condition, so if there are no teams, there will be no users:

Try this instead:

```
$users = collect();
foreach ($teams as $team) {
    $users = User::whereIn('id', $team->members)->get();
}
return view('project.index', compact('projects', 'users'));
```

But keep in mind that your loop will override the users each time, so you will just get the users from the last team only :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your loop.

There are some blurry parts in your code.

1) In every loop you over-write your `$users` variable: I will assume that you need an array so try something like:

```
        $users[] = User::whereIn('id', $team->members)->get();
```

*small note make sure that the column `members` in the `Team` table actually holds the ids.

2) The usage of `compact()` is correct but in case that your `$user` is empty then you will be trying to get an undefined property from it. In addition with the fact that you over-write your variable if the last itteration is empty then your `$user` is empty so you just return an empty array in your FrontEnd.

3) Using `whereIn` means that your column has more than 1 `Ids`. That's generally a bad practise. You should use a pivot table or store each record in different rows.

4) Predefine your array. If there are no teams, the `foreach` loop will never be accessed leaving you with a php error of undefined `$users`.